# How to test SSD with rPi 3B+ without dedicated SSD power supply?

Tags: usb-power

My 3B+ boots from a Western Digital Blue SSD. The nameplate under **the SSD  indicates 1.6A at 5V** so, I am really puzzled how it works at all off a USB port with no external power.

My WD Blue is wired in just like this stock photo:

[image]

**Is there a standard battery of SSD tests (reading / writing) that can determine if the rPi power supply is inadequate?**

I believe that best practice is to have a dedicated power supply for the SSD (USB hub)

Comment: AFAIK, the closest thing to the "standard battery of tests" that you mention is checking for the "low voltage warning"...  but somehow I don't think that's what you're after???

Comment: IIRC low voltage is a symptom of an inadequate power supply? (Exceeding current  limit)

Comment: It's a bit more subtle than that; e.g. many (most??) USB cables use a 24-26AWG wire for the power which can lead to resistive losses in the copper (wire) that can trigger low voltage. Long leads can also be problematic for greater resistive losses + greater inductance. **Anything** that causes the voltage to drop to 4.63V or less at the PMIC pin that monitors the 5V input will trigger a lo-volt warning. And FWIW, I have low-volt incidents on my RPi4 even though I am using RPi's "official" PS.

Answer (score 2):

N.B. this answer contains some speculation/opinions.

AFAIK, the only *"standard battery of tests"* that exist to *"determine if the RPi PS is inadequate"* is the RPi's built-in under voltage test; i.e. [`vcgencmd get_throttled`](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#get_throttled). Here's how you might use it to detect whether under-voltage conditions are occurring:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
throttled=$(vcgencmd get_throttled)
if [[ $throttled != "throttled=0x0" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "you've been throttled (\"$throttled\"); possibly due to undervoltage"
fi
```

Next, let's look at the ratings for RPi power consumption from the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements):

For your 3B+, the table states that *`Maximum total USB peripheral current draw`* is *`1.2 Amps`*, but they do not say how this value was derived/calculated. *REF Milliways Comment below:*<s>Did the RPi-folks conjur this 1.2A figure by subtracting the 1.34 max amperage drawn by the RPi 3B+ (Stress) from the 2.5 amp maximum current of the recommend USB Supply? Don't know - Pi hardware is proprietary.</s>

Next, let's look at SSD power consumption: You said, *"the SSD indicates 1.6A at 5V"*. I will guess that is an *absolute maximum* current draw figure; my guess is based on [figures provided here](https://ssdsphere.com/ssd-power-consumption-comparison/). I'll also guess that a typical current draw for a 2.5" SSD is 600 - 900 mA (based on the same reference).

Consequently, *specmanship* may have fostered some pessimism. That said, I do agree that a powered hub would likely be considered "best practice" (if there is such a thing with RPi :)

If it were my setup, I'd power the SSD from one of the Pi's USB ports, and set up the test (`vcgencmd` script) to run periodically. I'd monitor the results and proceed accordingly.

Comment: The Pi(3/2/B+) USB Current is supplied through a Current-Limited Power Switch (AP2553?) which limits current. My testing has confirmed this with a static load but the dynamic performance seems to indicate voltage is not maintained.

Comment: @Milliways: That's good to know; one less thing to speculate about :)

Comment: See post https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=334453. (... the maximum current is limited to 1200mA shared over all four USB ports)

Comment: @bstipe: Yep - that what the [table I ref'd in my answer](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements) says also. There's not a *current limiter* for each individual USB port - there's only one for all 4, and it doesn't care how it's divided as long as the total is < 1.2A.